# Hold and move image left or right like photo gallery on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image

Currently I'm using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to view the left or right each image, but the image move very fast.

Which way to hold and move the image slowly like iPhone Photos gallery?

On iPhone Photos we can move the image to left or right very slow and can see a part of next image. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UIScrollView. There's a tutorial here - http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content .

Comment: Very great. Thanks mattjgalloway so much.